# Brightway2: write_database() > "keywords must be strings"

Tags: brightway

I went to bed last night with my notebook working fine, but this lunchtime it was impossible to write my database after an Excel import. I went back to the example with [excel_importer_example.xlsx](https://github.com/maxkoslowski/Brightway2_Intro/blob/master/BW2_tutorial.ipynb) and followed the whole procedure online, but still got nothing, this same Error message araising:

```
TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

The step with imp.write_excel() worked well, the excel file is fine... I restarted the notebook, etc.
Any idea?

More information below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-1daab0bbe8d8> in <module>
----> 1 imp.write_database()

~\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\excel.py in write_database(self, **kwargs)
    275         """Same as base ``write_database`` method, but ``activate_parameters`` is True by default."""
    276         kwargs["activate_parameters"] = kwargs.get("activate_parameters", True)
--> 277         super(ExcelImporter, self).write_database(**kwargs)
    278 
    279     def get_activity(self, sn, ws):

~\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\base_lci.py in write_database(self, data, delete_existing, backend, activate_parameters, **kwargs)
    262                 warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    263                 db = Database(self.db_name, backend=backend)
--> 264                 db.register(**self.metadata)
    265 
    266         self.write_database_parameters(activate_parameters, delete_existing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what is indicated in the Excel example file, the empty lines before "Activity" are taken into account using the value `None`, which is not a string and makes bw2 crash.

The Excel file states that: "There can be blank lines before the activity definitions."

In my case, this is not possible and the empty cells must contain at least a " na " or " unknown ", and the blank lines should be deleted.

I am talking about these two tutorials:

- [Brightway-Seminar-2017](https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017/tree/master/Day%201%20PM)
- [Brightway2_Intro](https://github.com/maxkoslowski/Brightway2_Intro/blob/master/BW2_tutorial.ipynb)

Comment: Sorry for your frustration. I added a [test for blank lines](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/commit/5c60c7e1dc1901f21765adff0c208aa9bf25a31b) which passes on Windows and *nix. Could you provide more information on what could have changed from one day to the other? You can also contact me directly if you are willing to share the problematic input file.